# Is there any way to test array type query parameter in WireMock?

Tags: java, wiremock

In my case I want to test query parameters of a request like
`http://localhost/path?filter=filter1&filter=filter2`

What is the way to test this type of scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Request Matching](http://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/) to get matching query parameters. There are a number of different ways that this can be implemented and without knowing exactly what you would like to test, I don't think I can recommend one strategy over the others.

Answer (score 0):

As of now (Dec '22), there's no built-in solution utilising the RequestPatternBuilder. The corresponding GitHub issue for this is: https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock/issues/398 .

There is however a way to build this your own using `andMatching` as described in the issue's comment https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock/issues/398#issuecomment-778465146 :

```java
wireMockRule.stubFor(
  get(urlPathEqualTo("/path"))
  .andMatching(request ->
    MatchResult.of(
      Matchers.containsInAnyOrder("filter1", "filter2")
        .matches(request.queryParameter("filter").values()
    )
  )
)
```

or in Kotlin:

```kotlin
wireMockRule.stubFor(
  get(urlPathEqualTo("/path"))
  .andMatching {
    MatchResult.of(
      Matchers.containsInAnyOrder("filter1", "filter2")
        .matches(it.queryParameter("filter").values()
    )
  }
)
```